# How to design a set of tables in TSQL when a table that sets Types of records are involved and each type has differente fields?

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I am designing a set of tables in TSQL to store Alerts. For contextualization of the problem. An Alert has a Type. But a Type may have different fields For example, Type_1 will have 3 columns(Product_ID, Description, Price) and Type_2 will have 4 columns(Product_ID, Description, Price, Discount).

Should I create a separated Table for each type or only one Table, "Alert", with foreign key to Alert_Type table and have NULL fields when is not applied to a given type? In this case a row for Type_1 would have the Discount column NULL. Is this a correct way to tackle this type of problem?

Comment: You might want to consider creating an `Alerts` table with common information, e.g. `AlertId`, `AlertDate` and `AlertType`, and an `AlertsValues` table with name/value pairs appropriate to each alert, e.g. `AlertId`, `AlertPropertyId`, `AlertPropertyValue`. It sounds reasonable, but tends to be a nuisance in practice, e.g. what is the datatype of `AlertPropertyValue`? You could create a table for each alert type and one or more views that combine the tables for summary usage. It allows you to use the correct datatypes for each column and allows adding a new alert type in a consistent manner.

Comment: @HABO If I understand correctly that means that I will have an entry/row for each value that would be, in normal circumstances, in a column of one row right? If yes, than that means a lot of entries. What if I had a table Alert (AlertID, AlertTypeID, AlertDate) and than a table for each type of Alert where the primary key is the primary key of the table Alert? Does that seems correct? The worst of this solution is if in a near future instead of 2 type of Alerts I will have 30. Havind 30 tables, each one of a type of alert, seems daunting.

Comment: Using name/value pairs results in a lot of rows and a datatype trauma: do you make _all_ values `NVarChar(max)` or do you create a name/value table for each datatype? It doesn't get pretty. Having (many) tables for different alert types lets you use the correct datatypes, add check constraints and triggers to validate the data, index them appropriately, ... .  Don't worry about 30 tables, that isn't enough to bother the database. Tip: If you design tables using _database diagrams_ in SSMS you can cut'n'paste columns from one table to another.

Comment: @HABO I went with the route "A table per Alert_Type" which allows me, as you mentioned, to use the correct datatype, constraints and triggers. I think it allows me to have a more consistent solution a better understanding and "easy" maintenance. Thank you for your time and input.